# Scrapy enabling item pipeline

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

How do I enable item pipeline if I define the ItemPipeline class in the same file as my spider.
I tried the following but didn't work. Thanks.

```
process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
   'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'ItemPipeline': 100}
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the whole import path of the class.

For example, if your spider file is at `myproject/spiders/myspider.py`, use `myproject.spiders.myspider.ItemPipeline`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it would work but you can try `filename.ItemPipeline`.